# How to subset from a correlation coefficient dataframe

Tags: r

I am a very nubee in R and I am trying to subset from a corr. coefficient dataframe which is

`print(CD)`

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/kimoa.png]

and also
for
`corrplot(CD,method="number")`

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/rniCw.png]

So from all these coefficients, I would like to subset coefficients which is over 0.7
So I have tried a lots of code but it does not work.
Such as, `GG<-subset(CD,cor()>0.7) print(GG)`

How could I subset from such case? Thank you.

Comment: I am sorry for the images link :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to check by corplot your correlation.
Below a possible example

```
data(mtcars)
corr <- round(cor(mtcars), 1)
corr
      mpg  cyl disp   hp drat   wt qsec   vs   am gear carb
mpg   1.0 -0.9 -0.8 -0.8  0.7 -0.9  0.4  0.7  0.6  0.5 -0.6
cyl  -0.9  1.0  0.9  0.8 -0.7  0.8 -0.6 -0.8 -0.5 -0.5  0.5
disp -0.8  0.9  1.0  0.8 -0.7  0.9 -0.4 -0.7 -0.6 -0.6  0.4
hp   -0.8  0.8  0.8  1.0 -0.4  0.7 -0.7 -0.7 -0.2 -0.1  0.7
drat  0.7 -0.7 -0.7 -0.4  1.0 -0.7  0.1  0.4  0.7  0.7 -0.1
wt   -0.9  0.8  0.9  0.7 -0.7  1.0 -0.2 -0.6 -0.7 -0.6  0.4
qsec  0.4 -0.6 -0.4 -0.7  0.1 -0.2  1.0  0.7 -0.2 -0.2 -0.7
vs    0.7 -0.8 -0.7 -0.7  0.4 -0.6  0.7  1.0  0.2  0.2 -0.6
am    0.6 -0.5 -0.6 -0.2  0.7 -0.7 -0.2  0.2  1.0  0.8  0.1
gear  0.5 -0.5 -0.6 -0.1  0.7 -0.6 -0.2  0.2  0.8  1.0  0.3
carb -0.6  0.5  0.4  0.7 -0.1  0.4 -0.7 -0.6  0.1  0.3  1.0

install.packages('ggcorrplot')
library(ggcorrplot)
x<-cor(mtcars)
ggcorrplot(x, type = "upper", hc.order = TRUE)
```

[image]

Below a possible solution

```
library(caret)
#correlation matrix by pearson method
x<-cor(mtcars,method="pearson")
# numeric value for the pair-wise absolute correlation cutoff
hc = findCorrelation(x, cutoff = 0.7) 
#we sort the elements
hc = sort(hc)
#we delete the elements that has the correlation >=0.7
mtcars = mtcars[,-c(hc)]
#plots the elements that we choose
ggcorrplot(cor(mtcars), type = "lower", insig = "blank",lab = TRUE,digits = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however, if I do `library(caret)
x<-cor(AB,method="pearson")
hc = findCorrelation(x, cutoff = 0.7) 
hc = sort(hc)
AB = AB[,-c(hc)]`, I get a whole lot of numbers that are very high such as ``CC=F`  ARGT  EPHE   EWI   EWZ `HE=F` `KC=F` `LE=F`  SPYG   XLP `ZW=F`
   
 1   2560  30.0  32.5  29.7  36.8   66.5   123.   113.  55.3  67.2   614.
 2   2507  30.3  32.7  29.7  37.2   67.2   125.  ........

Comment: I was trying to get the coefficients over 0.7, but these numbers are quite huge. What do these numbers stand for and can I get the coefficients from these numbers?

Comment: I suggest you to plot your variables with a corplot and check your value. 
I refresh my answer. 
You have to study your correlation to understand when you can cut your data

Comment: Well what I wanted to do was to actually extract the numbers of coefficients but....still thanks I'll try more

Comment: I upload my answer with the coefficients.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. That is a very interesting way but can there be any way to make a correlation plot that looks like above of which the ones of value over 0.7?